# Docker not creating files on configured volume in YAML script

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose, yaml

I made the following script in docker-compose.yml, which tries to run a official PHP + Apache image from Docker Hub:

```
services:
  apache:
    image: 'php:5.6-apache'
    container_name: apache
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/apps/html:/var/www/html
      - /mnt/data/apps/ssl:/etc/ssl
      - /mnt/data/apps/apache:/etc/apache2
```

But when i run it with *docker compose up* the container does go up, but the files that were supposed to be created on container launch are not being created it... (Also happens when using docker run script)

If i remove the volumes, run it again and access the container with "docker exec -it apache bash" i see that the files are generated accordingly... Just happens when binding volumes. Wasnt the files suposed to be created automatically to the local volumes?

Please, what am i doing wrong? Is there something missing on the script? Am i being dumb?
Sorry if this is a really obvious question, i have nowere to go and are starting now on docker.

Thank you

Comment: Are the files in the `/mnt/data/apps/html` directory on the host before you start?  Are you on a native-Linux host or something else?

Comment: No, they're not. Well, of course HTML wont create itself, but what about configuration files? Do i need to get them BEFORE mounting or is it possible to make the image create the files automatically? Like when we do "apt install XX" the installation creates its configuration files, but with docker it does not happens when using persistent volumes, it only works when we do not specify a volume - Then, i can see the files created inside the container.

Comment: The `volumes:` block tells Docker, when the container starts up, to replace the image content in those directories with the corresponding host directories.  It sounds like you don't want `volumes:` here (maybe for the TLS certificates you still do) but rather to `COPY` your application into the image in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to run container without any volumes and use docker cp to copy the config files to my machine, then run it again but with volume poiting to the copied config files...

Nginx Example

```
docker pull nginx:1.23.1-alpine
docker run --name tmp-nginx-container -d nginx:1.23.1-alpine
docker cp tmp-nginx-container:/etc/nginx/ D:\Docker\Config
docker rm -f tmp-nginx-container
```